# ng2-charts update labels and data

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to create dynamically a chart using ng2-chart,
I get information from an angular 2 service, when I change only labels of chart it works and when I change data only it works, but When I change both just data are updated in the chart. have any one an explication  for this strange behavior.

my template :

```html
<canvas baseChart height="130" width="180"  
    [data]="doughnutChartData"
    [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
    [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

my class :

```
export class PlDoughnutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private homeService: TileServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updatePLdoughnut();

  }

  public util : UtilService = new UtilService();
  public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = ['Download Sales'];
  public doughnutChartData:number[] = [0,0,100];
  public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';

  public updatePLdoughnut(){

    this.homeService.getTile().
    then(res => {

      this.doughnutChartLabels =  res.PLtypes;
      this.doughnutChartData = this.util.objectToIntArray(res.PLByTypes);

    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Apparently, if you **do not modify the original reference** to the labels array, it seems to work, at least for me. I mean, if you want a completely different set of labels, you should do something like this:

In the template:

```
<canvas baseChart
  [datasets]="lineChartData"
  [labels]="lineChartLabels"
  [options]="lineChartOptions"
  [chartType]="'line'"></canvas>
```

In the ts component:

```
this.lineChartLabels.length = 0;
for (let i = tempLabels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  this.lineChartLabels.push(tempLabels[i]);
}
```

Or, using new ECMAScript syntax:

```
this.lineChartLabels.length = 0;
this.lineChartLabels.push(...tempLabels);
```

The key is maybe the `this.lineChartLabels.length = 0;` statement, which practically 'empties' your array by setting its length to 0, without modifying the reference.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same problem messing up the reference. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to point out that `ng2-charts` is again being actively maintained, and has been updated for Angular 7, with many bugs fixed and features added.

Answer (score 17):

Recently i had to use ng2-charts and i was having a very big issues with updating my data untill i found this sollution:

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas baseChart [datasets]="datasets_lines" [labels]="labels_line" [colors]="chartColors" [options]="options" [chartType]="lineChartType">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

and here what i have in my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'product-detail',
    templateUrl: 'product-detail.component.html'
})

export class ProductDetailComponent {
    @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

    private datasets_lines: { label: string, backgroundColor: string, borderColor: string, data: Array<any> }[] = [
        {
        label: "Quantities",
        data: Array<any>()
    }
];

private labels_line = Array<any>();

private options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
};


constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {

    this.getStats();

}
getStats() {

    this._statsService.getStatistics(this.startDate, this.endDate, 'comparaison')
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log('getStats success');
            this.stats = res;

            this.labels_line = this.getDates();
            this.datasets_lines = [];

            let arr: any[];
            arr = [];
            for (let stat of this.stats) {
                arr.push(stat.quantity);
            }

            this.datasets_lines.push({
                label: 'title',
                data: arr
            });

            this.refresh_chart();

        },
        err => {
            console.log("getStats failed from component");
        },
        () => {
            console.log('getStats finished');
        });
}

refresh_chart() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.datasets_lines_copy);
        console.log(this.datasets_lines);
        if (this.chart && this.chart.chart && this.chart.chart.config) {
            this.chart.chart.config.data.labels = this.labels_line;
            this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets = this.datasets_lines;
            this.chart.chart.update();
        }
    });
}

getDates() {
    let dateArray: string[] = [];
    let currentDate: Date = new Date();
    currentDate.setTime(this.startDate.getTime());
    let pushed: string;
    for (let i = 1; i < this.daysNum; i++) {
        pushed = currentDate == null ? '' : this._datePipe.transform(currentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        dateArray.push(pushed);
        currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
    re

turn dateArray;
    }    
}
```

i m sure this is the right way to do it, and hope this would be helpfull

Comment: sorry i didn't seen your post until the moment.

Comment: Hi, I have same issue, data without labels, labels update works if data is not updated... can you describe what is going on in your code, where is the important snippets that fix d the issue for you? My question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809229/ng-charts-not-updating-labels-when-chart-data-is-updated-at-same-time

Comment: Hey, I have tried your approach but it doesn't work for me. Can you help me get along with it ? Thanks. My question is in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204025/angular2-update-ng2-charts-with-labels

Comment: Hi @abdelhalim What is the logic behind using setTimeOut() ? Do we really need it? Is that the reason it's not working in my scenario too?

Answer (score 10):

Like Deyd pointed out before, this is caused by a combination of Angular 2+'s change detection and a bug in ng2-charts.

According to my own observations (correct me if I'm wrong), Angular merges several changes within a very short timeframe into a single collection (`changes: SimpleChanges`) when `ngOnChanges` is called.

Unfortunately, ng2-charts only checks if the **dataset** has been changed with this collection and updates it. Otherwise it completely rebuilds the entire chart. However, because of the way the change detection works, more than one property might have been changed. Then, only the dataset gets updated even if the labels and possibly other properties have been updated as well. See `ngOnChanges` in ng2-charts:
[valor-software/ng2-charts/src/charts/charts.ts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/src/charts/charts.ts)

And if you don't want to have a separate copy of ng2-charts in your app and fix the problem yourself, a possible workaround for this problem is to set the dataset with a short delay using JavaScript's built-in function `setTimeout(callback: () => void, delay: number)`.

Before:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>

  <canvas baseChart
          chartType="bar"
          [datasets]="barChartData"
          [labels]="barChartLabels"
          [colors]="barChartColors">
  </canvas>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  chartData: string[];
  chartLabels: string[];
  chartColors: string[];

  onChange(id: string) {
    getFromApiById(id)
      .then(result => this._setChart(result.data, result.labels, result.colors));
  }

  private _setChart(data: string[], labels: string[], colors: string[]) {
    this.chartData = data;
    this.chartLabels = labels;
    this.chartColors = colors;
  }
}
```

After:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>

  <canvas baseChart
          chartType="bar"
          [datasets]="barChartData"
          [labels]="barChartLabels"
          [colors]="barChartColors">
  </canvas>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  chartData: string[];
  chartLabels: string[];
  chartColors: string[];

  onChange(id: string) {
    getFromApiById(id)
      .then(result => this._setChart(result.data, result.labels, result.colors));
  }

  private _setChart(data: string[], labels: string[], colors: string[]) {
    this.chartLabels = labels;
    this.chartColors = colors;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chartData = data;
    }, 50);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using BaseChartDirective i did chart update and it served the purpose. Sample below:

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

inside the class add as below

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

While you have the values to be changed, add as below

```
setTimeout(() => {
if (this.chart && this.chart.chart && this.chart.chart.config) {
  this.chart.chart.config.data.labels = this.labels_pie;
  this.chart.chart.update();
}
});
```

Comment: By simply trusting on Angular's change detection, I got an error `element._view is undefined"`. The `update()` call does the trick! :)

Comment: This is the best solution imho. Data fetch is instant and the chart is not updated twice causing a janky effect.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is in clearing the label and data array, the below code didnt work for me :(
```

```
clearCharts() {
    this.barChartLabels= [];
    this.barChartData= [
      {data: [], label: 'label1'},
      {data: [], label: 'label2'}
    ];
  }
```

`However when I changed the way I cleared the data helped me (Using object reference)`

```
clearCharts() {
    this.barChartLabels= [];
    this.emptyChartData(this.barChartData);
  }
   emptyChartData(obj) {
     obj[0].data = [];
     obj[1].data = [];
     obj[0].label = 'label1';
     obj[1].label = 'label2';
  }
```

```

Comment: I want to let you know that this was the first solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using BaseChartDirective i did chart update and it served the purpose. Sample below:

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
```

inside the class add as below

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

While you have the values to be changed, add as below

```
 this.chart.ngOnChanges({});
```

Comment: @user738048 Thanks for correcting my answer, but if you corrected why did you not score ??

Comment: I can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in the library ng2-charts, to resolve it I have cloned the github of ng2-charts in my app directory and have done following steps :

- `npm install`
- in appmodule import ng-2charts.ts from src directory.
- add this `updateChartLabels` function to chart.ts file
- call it in the `onChanges` function.

public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.initFlag) {

```
  if(changes.hasOwnProperty('labels')){
    console.log('labels changes ...');
    this.updateChartLabels(changes['labels'].currentValue);
  }
//..
//...
}

private updateChartLabels(newLabelsValues: string[] | any[]): void {
this.chart.data.labels = newLabelsValues;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a walk around, for now you can put your labels and data in an object and put that object in an array and just loop through the array in your html. This will redraw the element every time your array changes.

in your type script every time there's a change.

```
data = [...]; labels = [...]; chartArray = [{data , labels }]
```

in your html

```
<canvas *ngFor="let chartData of chartArray " [datasets]="chartData.data" [labels]="chartData.labels" > </canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by turning the handler into an arrow function

```
export class HistogramChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: MyFruitService ) { }
  
  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = { responsive: true };
  barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwifruit', 'Blueberry', 'Orange', 'Grapes'];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartPlugins = [];

  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [45, 37, 60, 70, 46, 33], label: 'Best Fruits' }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService
      .getDocument("Foobar")
      .subscribe(this.handleResponse);
  }

  handleResponse = (doc: MyFruitDocument) => {
      console.log('document: ', doc);
      
      let labels = doc.dataPoints.map(p => p.fruitName);
      let data = { data: doc.dataPoints.map(p => p.value), label: 'Best Fruits' };

      this.barChartLabels = labels;    
      this.barChartData = [ data ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the current ng2-charts library.

Try the new ng4-charts library which has fixed this issue.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-charts

Comment: This is an age-old library with no updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it:

In your HTML you have

```
<canvas baseChart 
            [datasets]="ChartData"
            //...other stuff >
</canvas>
```

and in the component I have a function which update the chart with new data, and then I clone the datasets and re-assign it

```
drawChart(){
    this.ChartData=[{data: this.dataX, label: 'X'}]; // this.dataX has new values from some place in my code
    //nothing happened with my chart yet, until I add this lines:        
    let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ChartData));
    this.ChartData=clone;
   //other stuff like labels etc.
}
```

this works for me, hope it works for you too

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue when trying to update the labels, (specifically when trying to send a shorter array), And this solved it:

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart!: BaseChartDirective;
```

and then, when updating the labels:

```
this.chart.chart!.config.data.labels = [...]
```

No need to call the update() method.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't manage to get one of the above solutions to work properly, I want to contribute my solution, in case someone stumbles across this post and also got stuck with the present approaches.

I have the HTML similar to @mustafa918:

```
 <div>
  <canvas #canvas id="canvas" 
    baseChart [datasets]="lineChartData" 
    [labels]="lineChartLabels" 
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [options]="lineChartOptions" 
    [chartType]="lineChartType" 
    [legend]="lineChartLegend" 
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

And for the initialisation of the charts data in typescript i have:

```
public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
    { data: this.heights, label: 'Heights History', type: 'line', fill: false},
    { data: this.widths, label: 'Widths History', type: 'line', fill: false }];
```

And for me it worked only by setting the data and labels at the same time and don't use chart.update() - chart is the reference to the BaseChartDirective.

I loaded the respective data and labels beforehand, so that in *this.heights, this.width* and *this.lineChartLabels* are corresponding data.

E.g. : The entries on heights[i], widths[i] and lineChartLabels[i] match with the element in my *elementArray* at index i => element ={ "height":30, "width":20, "label":"box"}

```
setDatasets() {

//store data in chart references
var arrHeights = [];
for (var i in this.heights) {
  arrHeights.push({ x: this.lineChartLabels[i], y: this.heights[i] });
}

var arrWidths= [];
for (var i in this.widths) {
  arrWidths.push({ x: this.lineChartLabels[i], y: this.widths[i] });
}

this.lineChartData[0].data = arrHeights;
this.lineChartData[1].data = arrWidths;
```

}

I hope this helps someone :) Good Luck!

Comment: Not related to this question, But I was struggling to create a dynamic array in this format and your solution helped it. Thanks,                                                          
      arrHeights.push({ x: this.lineChartLabels[i], y: this.heights[i] });

Answer (score 0):

Today i struggled with similar problem, it appears there is a huge bug inside the updateChartData function of ng2-charts library version 1.6.0.

Here is the original function:

```
        updateChartData = function (newDataValues) {
            if (Array.isArray(newDataValues[0].data)) {
                this.chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    dataset.data = newDataValues[i].data;
                    if (newDataValues[i].label) {
                        dataset.label = newDataValues[i].label;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = newDataValues;
            }
        }
```

As you can see this updates only the data and the label, but all other properties are left behind. In my case i wanted to update also the pointBorderColor so i decided to override this.

First i get a reference to the ng2-charts library:

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: any;
```

It is very important the type is "any", because otherwise typescript will not allow me to override a private function.

Then i fix the bug in the function and override it in afterVIew init:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.updateChartData = function (newDataValues) {
            if (Array.isArray(newDataValues[0].data)) {
                this.chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    dataset.data = newDataValues[i].data;
                    if (newDataValues[i].pointBorderColor) {
                        dataset.pointBorderColor = newDataValues[i].pointBorderColor;
                    }
                    if (newDataValues[i].label) {
                        dataset.label = newDataValues[i].label;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = newDataValues;
            }
        }.bind(this.chart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Based on above answers, I extended this function and everything works fine now!

TS Code:

```
Declare : import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

          @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

           public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
               { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Data 1' },
               { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Data 2' }
             ];

           public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 
                  'Label5', 'Label6';

TS Function:

    refresh_chart(){
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.chart && this.chart.chart && this.chart.chart.config) {
            this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(x => {
              x.data = [];
            });
            let index = 0;
              this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(x => {
                x.data = this.lineChartData[index].data;
                index++;
              });
              this.chart.chart.update();
          }
      }, 500);
      }
```

HTML Code:

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]="lineChartData" class="canvas-wh" [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                                [options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                                [chartType]="lineChartType" [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked only after using ViewChildren and not ViewChild.

TS:

```
@ViewChildren('baseLineChart1') chart !: QueryList<BaseChartDirective>;

this.chart.forEach((child) => { child.update() })
```

HTML:

```
<canvas class="card-line-chart" baseChart #baseLineChart1>
```