# Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, charts, ionic3

this is my app.module.ts
I try with a tutorial this [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
imports: [
 ChartsModule
],
```

this is my html code page.html, i copy and paste from the tutorial

```
< div >
 < div style = "display: block" >
  < canvas baseChart
    [datasets] = "barChartData"
    [labels] = "barChartLabels"
    [options] = "barChartOptions"
    [legend] = "barChartLegend"
    [chartType] = "barChartType"
    (chartHover) = "chartHovered($event)"
    (chartClick) = "chartClicked($event)" > 
   < /canvas>
 </ div >
 < button (click) = "randomize()" > Update < /button>
</ div >
```

this is my typescript page also i copy and paste from tutorial. page.ts

```
public barChartOptions:any = {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
responsive: true};

public barChartLabels:string[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
public barChartType:string = 'bar';
public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'}
  ];

  // events
public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

public randomize():void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    let data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      (Math.random() * 100),
      56,
      (Math.random() * 100),
      40];
    let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.barChartData));
    clone[0].data = data;
    this.barChartData = clone;
  }
```

I try all tutorials and examples but i don't know what happen.
i get this error.
Error detail is:

```
**Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
          <div style="display: block">
            <canvas baseChart
                    [ERROR ->][datasets]="barChartData"
                    [labels]="barChartLabels"
                    [options]"): ng:///StatsPageModule/StatsPage.html@33:20
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            <canvas baseChart
                    [datasets]="barChartData"
                    [ERROR ->][labels]="barChartLabels"
                    [options]="barChartOptions"
                    [legend"): ng:///StatsPageModule/StatsPage.html@34:20
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("        [datasets]="barChartData"
                    [labels]="barChartLabels"
                    [ERROR ->][options]="barChartOptions"
                    [legend]="barChartLegend"
                    [chartT"): ng:///StatsPageModule/StatsPage.html@35:20
Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("      [labels]="barChartLabels"
                    [options]="barChartOptions"
                    [ERROR ->][legend]="barChartLegend"
                    [chartType]="barChartType"
                    (chartHo"): ng:///StatsPageModule/StatsPage.html@36:20
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("      [options]="barChartOptions"
                    [legend]="barChartLegend"
                    [ERROR ->][chartType]="barChartType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                  "): ng:///StatsPageModule/StatsPage.html@37:20**
```

I just want to make a graph that says the number of users and number of posts created during a week, but every tutorial that I follow I get error, all without exception, sorry my English is not native in case you have some spelling error.

Comment: Are you running a angular sample as ionic code (ionic serve) ?

Comment: is a ionic app v3

Comment: I do not think you can run a angular sample as ionic 3 without integrate it or rewrite it. Maybe try and put it into a ionic page.

Comment: all tutorials that i see about the chart in ionic they were just like that. a don't know make a chart in ionic then

Comment: you have seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629819/ng2-charts-update-labels-and-data ? and https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-add-ng2-charts-into-ionic/69347 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Setting up a chart in an Ionic App using Highcharts**

Install Highcharts for ionic:

```
 npm install highcharts –save
```

Open the file ***./src/pages/home/home.html***
and replace everything inside the ion-content tag with a div like this.

```
<div id="container" style="display: block;" ></div>
```

This div is a container to hold the chart. I write the code in ***home.ts*** file. The ***home.html*** and ***home.ts*** are the files in charge of creating the home page in the app.
In home.ts, on the top, import the ***highcharts*** module first.

```
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';
```

Next, create a function called ***ionViewDidLoad()*** inside the ***HomePage*** class, just after the constructor. The file should look like this:

```
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {}
}
```

The ***ionViewDidLoad*** is a special function which is executed after the View has been initialized and loaded; this makes sure to avoid any errors during the components’ access in the view. Create a new ***HighCharts.chart*** object in the ***ionViewDidLoad***:

```
var myChart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit eaten'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 0, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 7, 3]
  }]
});
```

Save the file, and in the terminal type `ionic serve –l` to run the app in the browser in the lab mode. The app should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a clash between versions of Angular and ng2-charts
With Angular 7.2.0 , I uninstalled ng2-charts and installed ng2-charts@2.2.3

This is helped. for more info. see:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1115