# Pie chart colors are not loading inside subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

I'm using [Ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) for drawing pie chart in the angular App.

If I assign `this.pieChartData` values inside `constructor` or `ngOnInIt`, pie chart is rendering properly without any issue.

```
ngOnInit () { this.pieChartData = [10,20]; } // works fine
```

But if i assign the values inside the `.subscribe` method, pie chart color is not rendering.

```
    this.service.getJiraOpenIssues('22407')
    .subscribe((response)=>{
     this.pieChartData = [10,20];
  });
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: have you tried to console.log to see if you actually getting there?(inside the subsicrbe)

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing data in `constructor` or in `ngOnInit()` it will works fine because `charts` get the data before rendering.

In your case you are passing data in `subscribe` then chart will not get your data.

You have to tell `chart` that you have a some new data. For that you have to use **.update()** method to update your chart's data. That's it.

Then your chart will render new updated data. :)

For detail example code view this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42692601/8612835). It may help you.