# Angular Radar Chart :OnClick event of label or sector

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts, radar-chart

I have a radar chart , in which I want that on click of label or that area it will switch to new page . It is possible in angular radar chart (ng2-chart). Please help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng2-charts update labels and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629819/ng2-charts-update-labels-and-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my recent answer on another post.
[I think this will help you, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073741/12272930)